# Java 2D array grid

Tags: java, grid, multidimensional-array

So basically I am trying to make a 9x9 grid for a minesweeper game. I need the grid to be filled with question marks to represent a minefield that has not been selected yet. **Ex: [?][?][?][?][?]** Basically my question is how would I get my program to output an array of question marks like that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class H4_Minesweeper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Game Description and rules
        System.out.println("Minesweeper is a very straightforward game, the rules are simple.");
        System.out.println("Uncover a mine (x), and the game ends. Uncover an empty square (o), and you keep playing.");
        System.out.println("A question mark (?) will represent tiles you have not uncovered yet.");
        System.out.println("Uncover a number, and it tells you how many mines lay hidden in the eight surrounding squares.");
        System.out.println("Use this information to carefully choose which squares to click.");
        System.out.println("\n\n\n");

        Scanner userin;


        String[][] board = new String [9][9];
        for (int r = 0; r<board.length;r++){
            for (int c = 0; c <board.length;c++){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: has your 2d array filled already? is there any reason that you want that expected output? is it gonna be 5 always?

Comment: No, sorry I should have mentioned that. I am completely new to arrays and I'm having trouble figuring the basis of it out.

Comment: I need the question marks to represent the unselected fields in a 9x9 grid. After I have that I will get user input to select a field they want to uncover. The five in my initial question was just an example to kind of get the idea of what the grid would start to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
for (int r = 0; r<board.length;r++){
   for (int c = 0; c <board.length;c++){
      board[r][c] = "?";  // Initialize the cell
      System.out.print("[" +board[r][c] + "]"); // Display the content of cell board
   }
   System.out.println();  // go to next line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you must initialize the array by setting all its elements to `"?"`:

```
String[][] board = new String [9][9];
for (int r = 0; r<board.length;r++){
    for (int c = 0; c <board.length;c++){
        board[r][c] = "?";
    }
}
```

Then you can print it:

```
for (int r = 0; r<board.length;r++){
    for (int c = 0; c <board.length;c++){
        System.out.print (board[r][c] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I guess you shouldn't redeclare `board` for printing :D.

Comment: @Tom true indeed. Copy-paste bug :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fill your 2d array with the String "?" for each of the grid spaces, and then, go row by row printing out the values of each array index

Filling array:

```
String[][] board = new String[9][9];

for(int y=0;y<9;y++){
    for(int x=0;x<9;x++){
        board[x][y] = "?";
    }
}
```

Displaying the rows:

```
for (int r = 0; r<9;r++){
    String line = "";
    for (int c = 0; c <9;c++){
        line+="["+board[c][r]+"]";
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: You could use a `StringBuilder` to avoid concatenation.

Comment: @Tom Why would I want to avoid concatenation... Using Stringbuilder in no way improves run-time speed... Also this is easier to understand and less typing